# Microsoft Outlook 2007 Limit attachment size

Tags: active-directory, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, email

I have qmail server and authetication on Active Directory. All clients use Microsoft Outlook 2007 as default mail client. A have one central location and several remote location wich are connected with slow link speed connection.

I have attachment limit on qmail, but i have problem when client attach file localy and send mail, attachment is been uploaded to qmail server and rejected because exceeded limit.

Is it possible to limit attachment localy on MS Outlook 2007?

I know that Office 2010 have attachment limitation but i think that is not working on Office 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2010 and 2013 have attachment limitation in environment where Exchange don't exist.

For office 2010 (Limit attachment size 10MB)

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences]
>   "MaximumAttachmentSize"=dword:00010240

For Office 2013 (Limit attachment size 10MB)

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences]
>   "MaximumAttachmentSize"=dword:00010240

Please save quoted text in file with .reg extension and use right click on them and merge. After this you will have added registry key for attachment limit.

Answer (score 3):

[No.  Outlook 2007 does not have the [native] ability to limit attachment sizes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/attach-a-file-or-other-item-to-an-e-mail-message-HP001231950.aspx#BM4).  Unfortunately for you, [that's an Exchange option only](http://exchangepedia.com/2007/09/exchange-server-2007-setting-message-size-limits.html).  There isn't even an official GPO or plugin option to control this on the client side (or an unofficial one that I've been able to find).

Comment: or a qmail limit in this case since it doesn't look like they are using exchange..

Comment: @Rex Indeed. I was addressing the OP's statement that `Office 2010 have attachment limitation`.  It's not Office 2010 doing the limiting, but Exchange.

Comment: Outlook 2010 have attachment limitation in environment where Exchange don't exist. [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences]
"MaximumAttachmentSize"=dword:00003000

Comment: @tasmanian_devil  Thanks, I didn't know that.  Learn something new every day.